# Search Dialog won't appear with TabHost implementation

Tags: java, android, search, tabactivity, activitygroup

I have created my tabs using the following example code and in the comments it was noted that many people could no longer call upon the search dialog and I have been able to no longer have my program force close when you click on the hardware search button but when you click on the button it doesn't pop up anything anymore.

Would anyone know how to fix this?

[Multiple Android Activities with TabActivity](http://ericharlow.blogspot.ca/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityGroup;
import android.app.LocalActivityManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Window;

/**
* The purpose of this Activity is to manage the activities in a tab. 
* Note: Child Activities can handle Key Presses before they are seen here.
* @author Eric Harlow
*/
public class TabGroupActivity extends ActivityGroup {  
private ArrayList<String> mIdList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
if (mIdList == null) mIdList = new ArrayList<String>();
}

/**
* This is called when a child activity of this one calls its finish method.
* This implementation calls {@link LocalActivityManager#destroyActivity} on the child         activity
* and starts the previous activity.
* If the last child activity just called finish(),this activity (the parent),
* calls finish to finish the entire group.
*/
@Override
public void finishFromChild(Activity child) {
LocalActivityManager manager = getLocalActivityManager();
 int index = mIdList.size()-1;

if (index < 1) {
finish();
return;
} 

manager.destroyActivity(mIdList.get(index), true);
mIdList.remove(index);
index--;
String lastId = mIdList.get(index);
Intent lastIntent = manager.getActivity(lastId).getIntent();
Window newWindow = manager.startActivity(lastId, lastIntent);
setContentView(newWindow.getDecorView());
}

/**
* Starts an Activity as a child Activity to this.
* @param Id Unique identifier of the activity to be started.
* @param intent The Intent describing the activity to be started.
* @throws android.content.ActivityNotFoundException.
*/
public void startChildActivity(String Id, Intent intent) {
Window window =    getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(Id,intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
if (window != null) {
mIdList.add(Id);
setContentView(window.getDecorView());
}
}

/**
* The primary purpose is to prevent systems before     android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR
* from calling their default KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK during onKeyDown.
*/
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
//preventing default implementation previous to android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR
return true;
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

/**
* Overrides the default implementation for KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
* so that all systems call onBackPressed().
*/
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
onBackPressed();
return true;
}
return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}

/**
* If a Child Activity handles KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK.
* Simply override and add this method.
*/
@Override
public void onBackPressed () {
int length = mIdList.size();
if ( length > 1) {
Activity current = getLocalActivityManager().getActivity(mIdList.get(length-1));
current.finish();
}
}
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
parentActivity.onBackPressed();
}
```

The following section explains how I used this ActivityGroup. The first thing I did was subclass this ActivityGroup like this.

```
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;

 public class TabGroup1Activity extends TabGroupActivity {
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 startChildActivity("OptionsActivity", new Intent(this,OptionsActivity.class));
 }
 }
```

I added this TabGroup1Activity into my TabActivity like this.

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1")
.setIndicator("MESSAGES")
.setContent(new Intent(this, TabGroup1Activity.class)));
```

Then any Activity that you want to start in the ActivityGroup can be done in a way similar to this.

```
Intent frequentMessages = new Intent(getParent(), FrequentMessageActivity.class);
TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
parentActivity.startChildActivity("FrequentMessageActivity", frequentMessages);
```

I have made all my activities searchable in the Android Manifest and I followed the tutorial on implementing search.

[Creating a Search Interface](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html)

Prior to modifying my code to work with the TabActivity the search was working as intended but something in the code has broken the search functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution which I am working on deciphering but I was hoping that someone with more know how would help in implementing it based on the example given in the tutorial example posted in the question.

Here is the solution that I found but haven't applied
[Nested TabHosts](http://app-solut.com/blog/2011/10/unexpected-behavior-when-working-with-nested-tabhosts/)